# symfony2/doctrine2 dql where field is not true

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

im having troubles with checking boolean field with "is not true" clause
im getting this error:

> ("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 510: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IS'")

query is build with dql. so in code i have it added like this

```
$dql .= " AND p.archived IS NOT TRUE ";
```

executed query:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id)
FROM Sandbox\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Pages\OfferPage p
INNER JOIN Kunstmaan\NodeBundle\Entity\NodeVersion nv WITH nv.refId = p.id
INNER JOIN Kunstmaan\NodeBundle\Entity\NodeTranslation nt WITH nt.publicNodeVersion = nv.id and nt.id = nv.nodeTranslation
INNER JOIN Kunstmaan\NodeBundle\Entity\Node n WITH n.id = nt.node WHERE n.deleted = 0
AND n.hiddenFromNav = 0
AND n.refEntityName = 'Sandbox\WebsiteBundle\Entity\Pages\OfferPage'
AND nt.online = 1 AND nt.lang = :lang AND p.archived IS NOT TRUE AND p.expirationDate >= :date ORDER BY p.price ASC
```

Comment: Try simplest: `AND p.archived = 0 AND` ...

Answer (score 10):

Normally when you have a boolean configured in Doctrine you have an integer field with 0 or 1. Its much easier to check if the value is `0` or `1`.

```
$dql .= " AND p.archived = 0";
```

or another solution:

```
$dql .= " AND p.archived = false";
```

or if you check to `null`

```
$dql .= " AND p.archived is null";
```

When you look at the page you can see some expression. `IS` can't be used in that context.

http://doctrine1-formerly-known-as-doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

And here is another link to show you how to use `where in` and `where not in`

http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/09/symfony-doctrine-where-in-and-where-not-in-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys. i have a nullable field. so i have done it with this because i need all that is not true.

```
$dql .= " AND (p.archived = 0 OR p.archived is null) ";
```